# Update custom views in one column of NSTableView based on editing a cell in another

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

In the first column of my view-based `NSTableView`, I have a custom `NSView` subclass. In the second column, there's an `NSTextField`.

Now I would like to adjust the drawing of the view in the first column based on when I start editing one of the text fields of the second column. I've tried setting a property on the custom view in `tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:`, but this doesn't work, as the table cells are only updated when I call `reloadData` on the table view, which in turn ends editing. To make this even more complicated, I'd like to adjust the drawing of the custom view not only in the row I'm currently editing, but for all the rows.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried setting `needsDisplay` or `reloadDataForRowIndexes:columnIndexes:`?

Comment: Using `reloadDataForRowIndexes:columnIndexes:` to only reload the first column seems to do the trick, thanks!

Comment: @Willeke could you please turn you comment into an answer so OP can accept and upvote it for future readers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `reloadDataForRowIndexes:columnIndexes:` to limit reloading to the first column.